# <ask> How to Separate paragraph to the sentence

Tags: php

hello can anyone help me to solve this probelm how to solve with this prblem, I wanna make sentence from this paragraph, i use the point as a separator paragraphs, but I have problem if a paragraph has a nominal number has a point that should be one part of the sentence. can anyone help me???

```
//$paragraf1 = $paragraf;
if(preg_match("/.*[0-9][.]/", $isi) != ""){
$isi = preg_replace("/([.])/", "", $isi); 
}
else
{
return $isi;
}

this code to separator paragraf with point ==> $paragraf = explode(".", $isi);
if(strlen($paragraf[count($paragraf)-1]) <= 1) unset($paragraf[count($paragraf)-1]);
//1. Case Folding
for($i=0; $i<count($paragraf); $i++){
//Merubah ke huruf kecil
$paragraf[$i] = strtolower($paragraf[$i]);
//menghilangkan tanda baca
$paragraf[$i] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/", "", $paragraf[$i]); 
}
//$_SESSION['paragraf'] = $paragraf;
print_r($paragraf); echo "<br/>";
exit();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fT74.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution should be that you explode on this

```
explode(". ", $isi);
```

Because well formated text has empty space after point and also numbers don't have this empty space.

Also if text is not well formated that means you need after exploding text to make a loop and to check every element in array if it has number on its end(last char) and on its begining (first char) of next element and if it has to join this two elements.

Comment: @AgungSetiabudi if this solve your problem please mark it as solved. If not let me know and try to writ a code for checking values of begining and end of letter in every elements of your array so it should work. And if you have more problems let me know.